# C# datagridView Autocomplete Textbox Font Change

Tags: c#

How can I chnge the FontSize of  AutoComplete Text in DataGridView

Answer (score 2):

In your Design View:

Properties:

[image]

It can be use

```
 dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
 dataGridView1.DataSource = lst;
 dataGridView1.Rows[0].Height = 200;
```

to customize the height of every specific row